# Searching log files using a Batch script (with user input)

Tags: search, batch-file, logging, user-input

I need to create a batch file [and unfortunately it has to be a batch file :( ] to pull information from a log, put that data into a new file, and then from the new file pull error text into another file. So I should end up with 3 files. The original log, the pulled thread, and the final log.

The thread number and error text is generally random and requires user input so that both the correct thread as well as the correct error are pulled.

Any and all help will be quite appreciated.

My log file might look like this

- 01/01/01 11:59:58:   thread 1234: Start
- 01/01/01 11:59:58:   thread 5678: Start
- 01/01/01 11:59:58:   thread 5678: *: Other Unnecessary information
- 01/01/01 11:59:58:   thread 5678: *: error error
- 01/01/01 11:59:58:   thread 5678: End
- 01/01/01 11:59:59:   thread 1234: *: Other Unnecessary information
- 01/01/01 11:59:59:   thread 1234: *: Other Unnecessary information
- 01/01/01 11:59:59:   thread 1234: End
- 01/01/01 12:00:00:   thread 1234: Start
- 01/01/01 12:00:00:   thread 1234: *: Other userful information
- 01/01/01 12:00:00:   thread 5678: Start
- 01/01/01 12:00:00:   thread 5678: *: Other Unnecessary information
- 01/01/01 12:00:00:   thread 5678: *: Other Unnecessary information
- 01/01/01 12:00:00:   thread 5678: End
- 01/01/01 12:00:00:   thread 1234: *: Other userful information
- 01/01/01 12:00:00:   thread 1234: ERROR ERROR ERROR
- 01/01/01 12:00:00:   thread 1234: *: Other userful information
- 01/01/01 12:00:00:   thread 1234: *: Other userful information
- 01/01/01 12:00:00:   thread 1234: End
- 01/01/01 12:00:01:   thread 1234: Start
- 01/01/01 12:00:01:   thread 1234: *: Other Unnecessary information
- 01/01/01 12:00:01:   thread 1234: *: Other Unnecessary information
- 01/01/01 12:00:01:   thread 1234: End

In this instance I am looking for thread 1234. Once that's in it's own file I want to pull the error text. Along with the lines from Start to End. So my final file would look like whats below.

- 01/01/01 12:00:00:   thread 1234: Start
- 01/01/01 12:00:00:   thread 1234: *: Other userful information
- 01/01/01 12:00:00:   thread 1234: *: Other userful information
- 01/01/01 12:00:00:   thread 1234: ERROR ERROR ERROR
- 01/01/01 12:00:00:   thread 1234: *: Other userful information
- 01/01/01 12:00:00:   thread 1234: *: Other userful information
- 01/01/01 12:00:00:   thread 1234: End

The number of lines above and below the error text can change quite significantly. My preliminary batch file is below.

```
@echo off
cls
:start
cls

::      Context Menu
echo  ____________________________________________________________
echo ^|     Please choose an option below.                ^|
echo ^|Search logs for specific error?                    [B] ^|
echo ^|Exit                           [X] ^|
echo ^|___________________________________________________________^|

::      Directory
set /p choice=" "
if '%Choice%' == 'B' goto :Searchlogs
if '%Choice%' == 'b' goto :Searchlogs
if '%Choice%' == 'X' goto :exit
if '%Choice%' == 'x' goto :exit
if '%Choice%' == ' ' echo "%Choice%" is not a valid option. Please try again.
if not %choice% == set choice =%choice:~0,1%
echo "%Choice%" is not a valid option. Please try again.

TIMEOUT /T -1
goto :start
cls
goto :start
TIMEOUT /T -1

:exit
cls
exit

:Searchlogs
echo Please enter the Thread number in format "1234"
copy \\Servername\log\logfile.log c:\users\%username%\Desktop\logfile.txt
copy \\Servername\log\logfile-1.log c:\users\%username%\logs\logfile-1.txt
set /p threadnumber=" "

find " %threadnumber%:" C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\logfile*.txt >C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%threadnumber%.txt
echo Please paste in error text.
set /p Errortext=" "
find "%Errortext%" C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%threadnumber%.txt" >C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Error.txt

TIMEOUT /T -1
goto :start
```

Comment: How do you determine the block of "1234 Useful information?" Your data has three blocks of 1234start..1234end. Please claify.

Comment: Each block of information 1. has a timestamp associated with it and 2. starts have to end before they begin again. So it could go start stop, start stop, start stop, however a single thread (1234 or 5678) can never start more than one process before finishing that process.

Comment: Ah - so you want the block of `start..end` for a thread that ontains "EOOR ERROR ERROR"?

Comment: That's correct. With that said I need the thread as well as the error to be able to change based on user input.

Answer (score 0):

```
type file.log | Findstr /c:"Thread 1234" > FileWithThreadInIt.txt

type FileWithThreadInIt.txt | Findstr /c:"Error" >FileWithThreadErrors.txt

type FileWithThreadInIt.txt | Findstr /v /c:"Error" >FileWithThreadNoErrors.txt

type file.log | Findstr /v /c:"Thread 1234" > FileWithOtherThreads.txt
```

Use variables

```
Set /p Thread=Enter thread number
type file.log | Findstr /c:"Thread %Thread%" > FileWithThreadInIt.txt
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to work? Just tested it and while it is creating the files it doesn't appear to write anything to them. Can I get some clarification?

Comment: try the additional parameter `/i` with the `findstr` to ignore capitalization

Comment: Right now I can't test with /I to check if that would fix the issue I was having earlier. In addition to that issue I was also hoping to allow user input for both the thread # as well as the error text. Could you explain how you'd go about doing that? (I've edited my original post to explain what I'm looking for a bit more clearly as well)

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET /p "findme=Identifier to find (eg thread 1234)"
SET /p "errortext=Error text to find (eg ERROR ERROR ERROR)"

FINDSTR /c:"%findme%" <q23318892.txt >threadfile.txt
SET "block="
SET "errorblock="
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (threadfile.txt) DO (
 ECHO(%%a|FIND "%findme%: Start" >NUL
 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET block=Y
 IF DEFINED block >>threaderror.txt ECHO(%%a
 ECHO(%%a|FIND "%findme%: %errortext%" >NUL
 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET errorblock=Y
 ECHO(%%a|FIND "%findme%: End" >NUL
 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  IF DEFINED errorblock GOTO done
  IF DEFINED block DEL threaderror.txt
  SET "block="
  SET "errorblock="
 )
)

:done
IF EXIST threaderror.txt (TYPE threaderror.txt) ELSE (ECHO threaderror.txt NOT created)

GOTO :EOF
```

This solution assumes that the first 'error' block is required. You'd need to set up the text to be found and filenames. I used a file named `q23318892.txt` containing your data for my testing.

---

fixed to suit further requirement: allow user-input

Comment: I edited my original post to explain what I'm looking for a bit better. But essentially I can't "SET "findme=thread 1234"" as that information along with the error text changes with each error. Do you know how you'd go about allowing user input for both the thread and error?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:Searchlogs
copy \\Servername\log\logfile.log c:\users\%username%\Desktop\logfile.txt
copy \\Servername\log\logfile-1.log c:\users\%username%\logs\logfile-1.txt
echo Please enter the Thread number in format "1234"
set /p threadnumber=
find " %threadnumber%:" C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\logfile*.txt > C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%threadnumber%.txt

echo Please paste in error text.
set /p Errortext=

set i=0
set "errorFound="
(for /F "tokens=1-4*" %%a in (C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%threadnumber%.txt) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set "line[!i!]=%%a %%b %%c %%d %%e"
   if "%%e" equ "End" (
      if defined errorFound (
         for /L %%i in (1,1,!i!) do echo !line[%%i]!
         echo/
      )
      set i=0
      set "errorFound="
   ) else if "%%e" equ "%Errortext%" (
      set errorFound=true
   )
)) > C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Error.txt
```

Example:

```
Please enter the Thread number in format "1234"
1234
Please paste in error text.
ERROR ERROR ERROR
01/01/01 12:00:00: thread 1234: Start
01/01/01 12:00:00: thread 1234: *: Other userful information
01/01/01 12:00:00: thread 1234: *: Other userful information
01/01/01 12:00:00: thread 1234: ERROR ERROR ERROR
01/01/01 12:00:00: thread 1234: *: Other userful information
01/01/01 12:00:00: thread 1234: *: Other userful information
01/01/01 12:00:00: thread 1234: End
```